# Sum of a certain series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'am having problems here. How to find the sum of this series?

The factoral is confusing me.
$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1} 2^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the index in the sum. You get 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-2)^n}{n!}.$$
Compare it with $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$ which is known.

Answer (score 1):

Shift the series with $j = n-1$ this will lead you to have

$$\sum_{j = 1}^{+\infty}\ \frac{(-1)^j 2^j}{j!}$$

This series can be seen as

$$\left(\sum_{j = 0}^{+\infty}\ \frac{(-1)^j 2^j}{j!}\right) - 1 = \left(\sum_{j = 1}^{+\infty}\ \frac{(-2)^j}{j!}\right) - 1$$

Now you know that there does exist an important series, which is

$$e^{x} = \sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty}\ \frac{x^k}{k!}$$

Comparing the two series, you can easily see that $x = -2$ thence you get

$$\sum_{j = 1}^{+\infty}\ \frac{(-2)^j}{j!} = e^{-2} -1 $$

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1} 2^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}  $$
1, Change index from 2 to 1. For every 'n' you need get same value as before.
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n} 2^{n}}{n!}$$
2, Remember that 
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n}}{n!} = e^{-1}=\frac1e$$

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-2)^{n}}{n!} = e^{-2}=\frac{1}{e^2}$$
3, But your index start at 1 no at 0. It means that you need subtract first member.

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n}}{n!} = 1+(-\frac11)+\frac12+(-\frac16)+...$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-2)^{n}}{n!}=\frac{1}{e^2}-1$$